# iOS - use Swift and Objective c at the same project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm working a project created by `iOS` and `swift` together. This project is a socket base app. In this app , data is stored in database and fetched from there. When i wanna get data from tables, I put fetching data to a `NSManagedObject` class as model and when i wanna use them , get them from their `NSManagedObject` model. also i should say the model classes are objective c base!! Now, when I wanna use this model data in swift class and cast them to a specific class, gives an error in runtime. please give me a solution. This is my Codes :

```
-(NSMutableArray *)loadBills : (int) estateId : (int) personId {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bill" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(personId = %d) AND (estateId = %d)",personId,estateId]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"billId" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [fetchedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSManagedObject *info in sortedArray) {
        Bill *bill=(Bill *)info;
        [array addObject:bill];
    }//for
    return array;
 }//loadBills
```

Swift code for casting is :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BillCell
    let sa = getBillData().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Bill
    print(sa.expDate)
    return cell
}
```

and the `getBillData()` function is :

```
private func getBillData() -> NSMutableArray {
    let dataLayer = DataLayer()
    let person = dataLayer.getCurrentPerson()
    let billArray = dataLayer.loadBills(person.estateId.intValue, person.personId.intValue)
    return billArray
}
```

and the error is :

> could not cast 'NSManagedObject_Bill_' to Bill.

Answer (score -1):

First of all it is not safe and not a good practice to load data from database in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function, Because this function will call every time you scroll the collection view, Instead load the Bill objects into an array and set as the datasource and populate the cells from that datasource. This could be another reason that you are getting nil object.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BillCell
    let sa = getBillData().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    print(sa.valueForKey("expDate")!.description)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging and see what you get for "sa" variable?

Comment: yeah ... for what?

Comment: @BinMan1, Debug and see what you are getting for variable "sa", Is it nil?

Comment: Dear downvoter, Please mention if there are any reason for downvoting, just downvoting won't help anyone. I can improve the answer if there is a reason and it will benefit for everyone who come across this kind of situation.